# C# DataTable - row's elements become null

Tags: c#, datatable

I have the weirdest bug - My application executes a code that causes 10 lines of results to be added to a DataTable, which is then shown on an Ultragrid.
Once in ~20 runs, the following scenario happens:
1. The first row is added to the data table:
`DataRow drNew = dtResults.NewRow();`
-- filling it with values --
`dtResults.Rows.Add(drNew);`
The row is not null, as I have a breakpoint after checking this: `if(drNew.IsNull(0))`.
2. The second row is added the same way, but after addition the following `if` is true:
`if(dtResults.Rows[0].IsNull(0))`.

Any idea how this thing can happen?

Thanks a lot.

**Edit** - changed the title to be more accurate, thanks.

**Edit 2:**

I've tried to catch RowChanging and RowDeleting events and check inside them whether
`dtResults.Rows[0].IsNull(0)` or `e.Row.IsNull(0)`, but I can't catch those at the time the first row changes its content from values to nulls.

Comment: I don't know if that is related to your problem or not (it probably isn't), but `drNew.IsNull(0)` nor `dtResults.Rows[0].IsNull(0)` does not, by more than implication, check if the *row* is null, it checks whether the value at the specified column index is null. That's a pretty big difference. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chk182xa.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`drNew.IsNull(0)` does not test whether a *Row* is null, is tests whether the data in the first column of the row is null. (likewise, `drNew.IsNull(1)` would check the second column).

Note that you are testing `drNew.IsNull(0)` and then `dtResults.Rows[0].IsNull(0)`. These might not refer to the same things - `drNew` is the row you are adding, and `Rows[0]` is the first row in the table. I think that if the DefaultView of the datatable has a Sort applied to it then `Row[0]` wont necessarily be the first one you added.

Comment: Edited the title, thanks. My problem is that at one point the first row has values in it and in the other one they're null. I'm checking both drNew and the table because I wanted to see where the values become null.

Comment: Are you sure that Rows[0] is returning the same row each time? If your DataTable is being sorted, it might be a different row. Another possibility is that something else is changing the values in the table. If your table is bound to a grid in the UI, then that could be the culprit.

Comment: No sorting, and the same line is missing every time. I have no idea how to find more changes to the table. I've tried wrapping it and in `set`, break if the value has a null row, but it doesn't help.

Comment: You could try the DataTable.RowChanging event, e.g. `dtResults.RowChanging += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changing);`

Comment: I've tried `if(e.Row.IsNull(0))` exactly there but for no good.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that event and then look at the Call Stack every time it gets called - this might shed some light on how the data is changing.

Comment: Also, maybe post more code in the question, it might give us clues.

Comment: My best guess at the moment is that the Ultragrid is the culprit, especially as you only get the problem occasionally.